# How to resolve No results were returned by the query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to change the password of the non-admin user in PostgreSQL using jdbc connection.

```
statement.executeQuery("ALTER ROLE user1 WITH PASSWORD '6789'");
```

This above query is throwing:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't: ALTER ROLE user1 SET PASSWORD '6789' ?

Comment: Using this psql query , I'm able to alter the password in pgadmin ALTER ROLE user1 WITH PASSWORD '6789' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

statement.executeQuery() expects a resultset and you don't get one. Use statement.execute() for an ALTER-statement to avoid this issue.

Link to the manual: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ddl.html

Comment: Using execute() method resolved my issue .. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.